# Why is the dot product non-zero for 90° rotated vector in xy plane?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, rotations

Let's consider a vector:
$$
\vec V = (x\, y\, z)^T
$$

$\vec W$ is the vector obtained by rotating $\vec V$ about $z-$axis by $90^\circ$.

$$
\vec W = R_z\left(90^{\circ}\right)\left[\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos 90^{\circ} & -\sin 90^{\circ} & 0 \\
\sin 90^{\circ} & \cos 90^{\circ} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{l}
-y \\
x \\
z
\end{array}\right]
$$

But the dot product of $\vec V$ and $\vec W$ is clearly non zero for arbitrary $z$:

$$
\vec V \cdot \vec W = -xy + xy + z^2 \neq 0
$$

What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: What do you think happens if you take for instance  $v = (0,0,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take an arbitrary vector (in a space with 3 dimensions), and rotate it $90^\circ$ about an arbitrary axis, the result is usually not orthogonal to what you started with. In this particular case, consider the vector $[0,0,1]^T$, and think about what should happen as you rotate it.

You can even see this in your calculations: $\vec V \cdot \vec W = -xy + xy + z^2 = z^2$. That tells you that the clue is the $z$-coordinate of $\vec V$. It doesn't tell you yet whether it is your calculations that are wrong, or your conceptions, but it tells you exactly where the two are different, and thus why I and Hyperplane above tell you to use the exact same example vector.

Comment: What is the procedure to get the perpendicular vector to that then?

Comment: There isn't a "**the** perpendicular vector". There is a whole plane of them to choose from (for instance, if your initial vector is along the $z$ axis, you can choose any vector in the $xy$-plane). And it's even been proven (the so-called "hairy ball theorem") that in odd dimensions like here, there isn't really a "nice" consistent and continuous way of doing it, the way for instance $(x, y, z, w)\mapsto (y, -x, w, -z)$ will always work in 4 dimensions.

Comment: What a shame, math always embarasses me even for things that I have always thought are basic. Thank you for your answer